# SQL/Postgres: Find Tuple with Same Value (for a Given Value in another column)

Tags: sql, postgresql

My table ANSWERS_T is

```
id    answer_date_val             event_id
..    ...                         ...
103   2019-10-18 09:30:00.000     145
104   2019-10-18 09:35:00.000     145
105   2019-10-18 10:45:00.000     146
106   2019-10-18 10:50:00.000     146
..
```

My query needs to find ANSWERS_T rows where there are **multiple identical answer_date_val for the same event_id**.

This is in Postgres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need duplicated entry for answer_date_val and event_id, you could try using a subquery for duplicated joined to the base table

```
  select * 
  from ANSWERS_T a 
  inner join  (
      select  event_id, answer_date_val
      from  ANSWERS_T
      group  by event_id, answer_date_val
      having count(*) >= 2 
  ) t on t.event_id= a.event_id
      and t.answer_date_val = a.answer_date_val
```

Comment: thanks, something is malformed, getting this:
`ERROR:  syntax error at or near "event_id"
LINE 6:       group  event_id, answer_date_val`

Answer (score 1):

You can get the rows using:

```
select a.*
from answers_t a
where exists (select 1
              from answers_t a2
              where a2.event_id = a.event_id and
                    a2.answer_date_val = a.answer_date_val and
                    a2.id <> a.id
             );
```

I would be inclined, though, to summarize this:

```
select event_id, answer_date_val, array_agg(id)
from answers_t
group by event_id, answer_date_val
having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: thanks the 1st query works, the 2nd gives a very large number of rows

Comment: @geneb. . . (1) I would think the second would return *fewer* rows than the first.  Are you sure you have the `having` clause?  (2) The `exists` is likely to be faster than `join` with `group by`.  You can, of course, accept any answer you like, but I'm pointing that out.